# How to see which Maven modules are processed in parallel in a Maven build with multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, parallel-processing, maven-3

When running a Maven build with only one thread, the Maven modules get processed sequentially.

However, [when using multiple threads in a Maven build](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3), some Maven modules will be processed in parallel. Which and how many modules will be processed in parallel depends on the dependencies that the modules have to each other.

Is there a way to see which Maven modules can and will be executed in parallel? Maybe something like a Maven execution plan?

Comment: First question: Is there a particular reason behind the question a kind of a problem? Or just based on curiosity ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'd like to find out which number of CPU threads is enough to maximize the build performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to see which Maven modules can and will be executed in parallel? Maybe something like a Maven execution plan?

At the moment there is no way to see that upfront. Technically it could be analysed based on the topoligicaly sorted tree of the modules.